# Java Play Framework findAll returning duplicates

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm creating a simple Twitter scraping application.  I have a job on application start that is correctly querying Twitter and saving the data to a MySQL database.  The issue I am coming across is when I try to do a dump of this data.  The list I get back from `Model.findAll()` is returning X amount of duplicates, where X is the total number of rows from that table.

The Controller code is as follows:

```
List<Tweets> tweets = Tweets.findAll();
render(tweets);
```

The HTML code is as follows:

```
#{list tweets, as:'tweet'}
    <div class="tweet">
        <span>
            ${tweet.tweet_text} 
        </span>
    </div>
#{/list}
```

I've messed around with code in the controller though and found that this works to get back each of the tweets:

```
List<String> tweets = Tweets.find("SELECT tweet_text FROM Tweets tweets").fetch();
```

If I select more than one column I could return it to a `List<Object>` object, iterate through that list, and create `List<Tweets>` object from it, but I know this is the wrong way to do it.  Any advice is helpful on what I could be missing.

tl;dr; `Model.findAll()` is returning duplicates and I have no idea why.

**EDIT**: For those who are asking, there are *no* duplicates in the database.

Comment: Have you validated that you do not import duplicates into MySQL?

Comment: Do you have any eagerly fetched association in this entity? Knowing its mapping would help.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, there are no duplicates in this table.

Comment: @JBNizet What do you mean by "eagerly"?

Comment: An association can be configured as eager or lazy. And if it's configured as lazy, a request can override the default an load the association eagerly (using `fetch` in the query). So, do you have a collection in the Tweet entity that is marked as eager?

Comment: @JBNizet No, I do not.  I do not have any collections defined in the Tweets controller.  Does there need to be one?

Comment: if this is still rellevante i came across the same issue, and upon debugging the sql statements Hibernates generates i noticed a problem with the key matching of the desired table. you can use the `@Id` annotation or the `@EmbeddedId` for a composite key.

Comment: @LNendza any solution to this? I am facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you are not inserting duplicates as opposed to fetch them?. You could query your database to find out for sure.

One way to not display duplicates (but not to solve the underlying issue) is to use the following query:

```
List<String> tweets = Tweets.find("SELECT tweet_text FROM Tweets tweets group by tweet_text").fetch();
```

Comment: Yes, the data going into the database is unique and when I run your query I get the same results as the query I had posted.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to have duplicates is when you fetch a child object with the parent one. The join is causing duplicates. In this case you can do

```
SELECT distinct tweet from Tweets tweet
```

to remove the duplicates

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?  What do you mean by "fetch a child object with the parent one"?

Comment: If your tweet object as a child object, for example one tweet can have multiple tags and you do some eager loading (like join fetch in hql) then if a tweet have two tags, you will have it twice in the result unless you use the distinct keyword